# Присваивать значение переменной или просто обращаться к классу?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Здравствуйте, интересует такой вопрос.

Лучше присваивать значение переменной, а потом приравнивать ее к null, или достаточно просто вызвать класс?

Поясню вопрос на примере.

Приберет ли сборщик мусора после такой конструкции?

```
System.out.prinln(new Date());
```

Или лучше сделать так?

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
date = null;
```

Comment: Соберёт. Используйте первый вариант. Можно и второй, но исправьте String date на Date date и уберите date = null

Comment: Благодарю!
На счет Date - не углядел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Касательно примера, то оба варианта не имеют никакой разницы, внутри компилятор создаст практически идентичный байт-код для обоих вариантов.
Использовать экземпляры объектов или анонимные классы в данном случае вопрос стиля и читаемости кода, не более. Естественно, что если объект будет использоваться повторно, то логичнее создать его экземпляр и работать с ним.

Приравнивать объект к `null` после использования обычно не требуется, GC и так удалит объект, когда он больше не будет нужен.